# call controller from javascript on view using codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

hey guys i am facing trouble in calling controller method from javascript pls help . .

my view is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function kccbranchselect()
    {
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : 'addreceiptkccbranchid='+ $('#addreceiptkccbranch').val(),
        url : '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ctl_dbcont/getmembersbybranch',
        success :   function(data){
                        $('#addreceiptddsmember').val(data);
                    }
        });
    }
</script>
<select id="addreceiptkccbranch" name="addreceiptkccbranch" onChange="kccbranchselect();" tabindex="1" >
    <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
    <?php foreach($branchlist as $value):?>
        <option value="<?=$value['branch_id']?>"><?=$value['branch_name']?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<select id="addreceiptddsmember" name="addreceiptddsmember" tabindex="1">
    <?php foreach($member_by_branch as $row) { ?>
        <option value = ""></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

my controller is

```
function getmembersbybranch()
{
    $this->load->model('mod_user');
    $addreceiptkccbranchid      =   $_POST['addreceiptkccbranchid'];
    $data['member_by_branch']   =   $this->mod_user->member_receipt_dds($addreceiptkccbranchid);
    redirect('view_addreceipts');
}
```

i am generating a dropdown by selecting another dropdown option . . i cant access the controller method by putting `url : '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ctl_dbcont/getmembersbybranch',` in ajax ,why ??

Comment: that not a controller but only a function inside class controller.

Comment: yeah its right . . how can i call this function from javascript @Kaii

Comment: You are already calling it! But what is redirecting doing in ajax code?

Comment: my problem is when i select an option from first select the onchange call javascript function and from this function i call controller at this time the controller function does not access

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution for this to work

AJAX Request

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    data : 'addreceiptkccbranchid='+ $('#addreceiptkccbranch').val(),
    url : '<?php echo site_url("ctl_dbcont/getmembersbybranch");?>',
    success :   function(data){
                $('#addreceiptddsmember').val(data);
    }
});
```

Controller

```
function getmembersbybranch()
{
    $this->load->model('mod_user');
    $addreceiptkccbranchid      =   $_POST['addreceiptkccbranchid'];
    $data['member_by_branch']   =   $this->mod_user->member_receipt_dds($addreceiptkccbranchid);
    $this->load->view('member_by_branch',$data);
}
```

View

```
<?php
if($member_by_branch){
    foreach($branchlist as $value):
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$value['member_id']?>"><?=$value['member_name']?></option>
    <?php 
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

Redirect will not work. Create a simple view for dropdown oprions.

Comment: the second dropdown option is on same view on which first drop down,that means when i select a value from first drop down this page should load again.  . .

Comment: can i call same view in `$this->load->view('//same view here',$data);`  or should i make a new view @raheel shan

Comment: this is nice answer but by `url : '<?php echo site_url("ctl_dbcont/getmembersbybranch");?>',`i can not go to `getmembersbybranch`

Comment: well @Jay it was only example you can load same view and use controller method according to your requirement

Comment: i want `'addreceiptkccbranchid='+ $('#addreceiptkccbranch').val(),` send to `url : '<?php echo site_url("ctl_dbcont/getmembersbybranch");?>',` but not work . .

Answer (score 0):

The `redirect` statement here is invalid, as it is an AJAX request. You have to send html or json response from server, which you can process at client side. e.g.

```
$data['member_by_branch']=$this->mod_user->member_receipt_dds($addreceiptkccbranchid);
echo $data['member_by_branch']; //assuming its html
```

so on client side, you just have to use this statment in you callback method.

```
$('#addreceiptddsmember').html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Replace your js function by this function:

```
$("#addreceiptddsmember").live("change",function(){

   var htmlString="";
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:'addreceiptkccbranchid='+ $('#addreceiptkccbranch').val(),
        url:'ctl_dbcont/getmembersbybranch',
        datatype:'application/json',
        success:function(data){
          $.each(data,function(i){
             htmlString+="<option  value='"+data[i].branch_id+"'>"+ data[i].branch_name +"</option>"
          });
          $('#addreceiptddsmember').html(htmlString);
     }
  });
});
```

in this you have to make `htmlsting` and append to selected list using jquery it won't be available in php foreach as you were doing using in the view code.

also remove

```
redirect('view_addreceipts');
```

& replace it by:

```
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

in the controller

hope it help!

Comment: still i can't access the methoe from url:url:'ctl_dbcont/getmembersbybranch',

Comment: ajax not work for me . . `$('#addreceiptkccbranch').val(),` this data does not pass to `url:url:'ctl_dbcont/getmembersbybranch',`

Comment: @Jay I m sorry it was a typo now test this one and add alert("success") in the success function of ajax

Comment: yeah alert works then why data is not pass to that method . . @sandip

Comment: @Jay do you have firebug extension for firefox, check whether the data is getting passed or not, and if the data is not coming from the controller function then there is something wrong with database query etc